# Forward HTTP request to another server

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, http-post

I have the following code that receives webhook messages:

```
// Read posted data
string requestBody;
using (var reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream))
{
    requestBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
requestBody.Log();

// Attempt to forward request
context.CopyTo(Settings.Payments.Paypal.ScirraPaypalIPNEndpoint);
```

`requestBody` contains data which is logged.  I then attempt to forward the request to another URL:

```
    public static void CopyTo(this HttpContext source, string url)
    {
        var destination = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);

        var request = source.Request;
        destination.Method = request.HttpMethod;

        // Copy unrestricted headers
        foreach (var headerKey in request.Headers.AllKeys)
        {
            if (WebHeaderCollection.IsRestricted(headerKey)) continue;
            destination.Headers[headerKey] = request.Headers[headerKey];
        }

        // Copy restricted headers
        if (request.AcceptTypes != null && request.AcceptTypes.Any())
        {
            destination.Accept = string.Join(",", request.AcceptTypes);
        }

        destination.ContentType = request.ContentType;
        destination.Referer = request.UrlReferrer?.AbsoluteUri ?? string.Empty;
        destination.UserAgent = request.UserAgent;

        // Copy content (if content body is allowed)
        if (request.HttpMethod != "GET"
            && request.HttpMethod != "HEAD"
            && request.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            using (var destinationStream = destination.GetRequestStream())
            {
                request.InputStream.Position = 0;
                request.InputStream.CopyTo(destinationStream);
                destinationStream.Close();
            }
        }

        if (!Settings.Deployment.IsLive)
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
                (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
        }

        using (var response = destination.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            if (response == null) throw new Exception("Failed to post to " + url);
        }
    }
```

The handler that receives this forwarded request has the code:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string requestBody;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream))
    {
        requestBody = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    requestBody.Log();
}
```

However on the handler forwarded to, `requestBody` is always empty!  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `request.ContentLenght is` not set. Then, silly question, does the server support HEAD requests?

Comment: @Jimi content length is set automatically when writing to the request and yes destination server supports HEAD, OPTION, GET, POST

Comment: So, what's the StausCode of the response?. Is there a proxy between the two? I'm asking because there's nothing special in the code. Of couse you have tried a POST passing data you have control over.

Comment: @Jimi thanks for helping - managed to find the issue.  It only fails in production because both servers are hosted in Cloudflare which causes a CF 1000 error - prohibited DNS.  Resolution is to specify target server IP in origin servers hosts file.

Comment: @TomGullen Please [join me in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29074/html-css-webdesign) about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910047/stop-child-list-elements-having-style-applied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both servers are hosted in Clouflare, when posting from one to the other I get a CF 1000 prohibited IP error.

Solution is to add target servers IP address into requesting servers hosts file.